# Starting animation in Gif

Tags: images

I have a variable that holds a GIF image

```
my-image's value is
(image :type gif :data "GIF89a+
[...]
```

I add it to a buffer and it is being displayed

```
(insert-image my-image)
```

But the animation is not being shown. I try to do

```
(image-animate my-image 0 t)
```

but the animation does not start either. If I ask the current frame

```
(image-current-frame my-image)
```

It always return zero.

How can I start the animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An animated GIF is a multi-frame image to Emacs.  You can display an arbitrary frame of it by specifying the `:index` property in the image specification.  `image-animate` does modify the index of the given image specification with a timer.

That being said, [it works for me](http://brause.cc/video/emacs_animated_gif.mkv).  What you could do is finding the definition of `image-animate` with `M-x find-function`, then instrument it with `C-u C-M-x` and step through its execution to see what's going wrong.  Alternatively, try figuring out whether something about the image spec is wrong, like by using an absolute file name as argument to `create-image`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know about find-function. Looks like image-multi-frame-p is always returning nil as if no image was animated. I'll continue debugging. image-metadata is always returning nil too.

Comment: Probably related to this https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=21714 I was able to find it thanks to your comment so I'm marking as accepted

Comment: OSX will never animate -- I filed a bug a few months ago.  Windows builds work properly when built with and contain the necessary libraries.

Comment: I could get GIF animations working inside Emacs on Windows platform, note that you need a right compiled Emacs and some libraries.