# Open org-mode link of gif image and display inside of Emacs buffer with command image-animate

Tags: org-link, animate

I want to open gif image link (in Org-mode) with emacs lisp function
`image-animate`. Here is my try.
https://gist.github.com/e2e05b28e0a6bf3bd9f27f345696892d But I got some
problems, how to open a temp buffer window to display the image? and Seems
`image-animate` require IMAGE as absolute path. I don't know how to use
`org-file-apps` parameters FILE and LINK.

Usually the org-mode GIF file link looks like this:

`[[file:data/eb/cf96ad-9e34-4ef6-b0c2-5c31bb869aa6/59715_170807115059_1.gif]]`

Comment: A related question is here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19218/starting-animation-in-gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you were already very close.

Starting from your code I ended up with the entry

```
(lambda (file link)
  (let ((my-image (create-image file))
        (tmpbuf (get-buffer-create "*gif")))
    (switch-to-buffer tmpbuf)
    (erase-buffer)
    (insert-image my-image)
    (image-animate my-image)))
```

for ".gif" in variable `org-file-apps`.

I think the main issue with your code was that you did not give the buffer enough time to live.

Comment: Do you know how to loop playing the gif?

Comment: Set the third parameter to `image-animate` to t for endless repetition.  For the example above this is `(image-animate my-image nil t)`.  See the documentation of `image-animate` for further information.